# Union two tables with different columns and display null in the output

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have two tables, customer_tbl and suppliers_tbl
how do I union this two tables if they are different in columns?

customers_tbl:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/0ATK6]

suppliers_tbl:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/6hj3t]

and this should be the output:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/0vtiX]

I tried this using union and left join but it has an error.

This is my code

```
select customerid, customername,
       contactname, address,
       city, postalcode, country 
from customer_tbl
left join (select supplierid as customername, 
                  address, city,country 
            from suppliers_tbl) 
  on customertbl_customername = suppliers_tbl.supplierod as customername;
```

Comment: post the sample data instead of posting images ...it will not help much

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for union you can add  null value for match number and type

```
select
     customerid
     ,customername
     ,contactname
     ,address
     ,city
     ,country 
     ,postalcode
     from customer_tbl
union 
select 
     supplierid
    ,suppliername
    ,contactname
    ,address
    ,city
    ,country 
    , null
from suppliers_tbl
```

in you sample you have some columns not macthing  so you can use null for these columns

Comment: what do you mean .. the supplierid should return the value in yoru table  .. (added suppliername and contact name )  .. answer  updated